# pgloader: Migrate SQL Server database to PostgreSQL: How to filter by scheme?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, pgloader

I'm learning pgloader. I want to migrate a database in SQL Server to PostgreSQL but only certain schemas. In the documentation, I have noted the following:

> including only table names like 'GlobalAccount' in schema 'dbo'

Following this example, I would like it to include all the tables of this schema. How can I do that?